# How do I program a select folder dialogue in C++?

Tags: c++, directory

I've been searching extensively but all of the resources are somewhat confusing as I'm very novice in programming and trying to learn. When I copy their source code over, it often has errors.

I looked on the microsoft website and found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx

But it was even more confusing and I"m terribly lost now. I'm open to pretty much any method, thanks!

Comment: That thing is a .NET class, you can't use it in a "normal" C++ project...

Comment: Plain C++ has no GUI components. What environment are you programming for? What framework?

Comment: I'm not particularly sure what is meant by that. I'm on windows 7 using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I suggest you look at Qt at http://www.qt.io/ and Qt Creator at http://www.qt.io/ide/. This toolkit is pretty powerful, you have a good IDE (Qt Creator), you can do zillions of things, there is a default file/folder selection dialog you can customize, and it's rather easy to port Qt applications to other operating systems like Linux or MacOS. If you want to design a GUI application, this is worth a close look. Besides, you can even integrate OpenGL graphics into your windows ...

Comment: Qt is an excellent GUI framework, but for a novice is not adequate, it uses its own syntax and semantics on top of C++. This would confuse a lot the asker.

Comment: Hmmmm. But it has extremely good documentation, and great tutorials. Maybe it's overkill, but still, I think it's very educational to start using Qt. Of course it has it's own class system, so your point is valid as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want SHBrowseForFolder:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The problem is that `SHBrowseForFolder` is quite a PITA to use even if you know how WinAPI/shell programming works, so I doubt that a novice can figure out how to use it by itself...

Answer (score 0):

First of all: walk before running.

Try to learn language appropriately step  by step with some online tutorial like this:

http://www.learncpp.com

Graphical user interface is harder than basic programming. Once you know a language then select a GUI toolkit. Win32 and MFC are the classic c++ windows toolkits, but are not my favorites. As a novice perhaps you should try Java o C# before C++.

wxWidgets, GTKmm and Qt are better C++ GUI frameworks in my opinion. Each has its own hurdles. Try to learn the language and your IDE (Visual Studio, Codelite,Code::Blocks,e tc)  configuration and usage to program effectively.